# Why the etching profile of HF and HCl on titanium surface is different?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

[image]

Why the profile of etched titanium with HF-HNO3 looks like a hill, while the profile of etched titanium with HCl is U-shaped? Can you please put your source if you know it? Thank you

Note: the picture above is the profile of etched titanium with HF

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking. Have you considered the sample curvature before etching? The picture above shows it quite clearly.